# Node.js "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" when loading socket.io.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, socket.io, pug

I have simple application to test socket.io using node.js and express framework

There are some files relating to my app

File server.js

```
var express = require('express');

var env = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);

var config = require('./server/config/config')[env];

require('./server/config/express')(app, config);

/////////////////////////// Database ////////////////////////////////
require('./server/config/mongoose')(config);

/////////////////////////// Passport ////////////////////////////////
require('./server/config/passport')();

/////////////////////////// Routes ////////////////////////////////
require('./server/config/routes')(app);

/////////////////////////// Socket ////////////////////////////////
require('./server/config/socket')(server);

/////////////////////////// Port ////////////////////////////////
app.listen(config.port);
console.log("Listening on port " + config.port + '...');
```

File express.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    stylus = require('stylus'),
    passport = require('passport');

module.exports = function(app, config){
    function compile(str, path){
        return stylus(str).set('filename', path);
    };

    app.configure(function(){
        app.set('views', config.rootPath + '/server/views');
        app.set('view engine', 'jade');
        app.use(express.logger('dev'));
        app.use(express.cookieParser());
        app.use(express.bodyParser());
        app.use(express.session({secret: 'test whiteboard unicorns'}));
        app.use(passport.initialize());
        // using session
        app.use(passport.session());
        // config Stylus middleware
        app.use(stylus.middleware({
            src: config.rootPath + '/public',
            compile: compile
        }));
        app.use(express.static(config.rootPath + '/public', { redirect : false }));
    });
}
```

script.jade

```
script(type="text/javascript", src="/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js")
script(type="text/javascript", src="/vendor/angular/angular.js")
script(type="text/javascript", src="/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js")
script(type="text/javascript", src="/vendor/toastr/toastr.min.js")
script(type="text/javascript", src="/vendor/restangular/dist/restangular.min.js")
script(type="text/javascript", src="/vendor/lodash/dist/lodash.min.js")
script(type="text/javascript", src="/vendor/jquery-minicolors.min.js")
script(type="text/javascript", src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")
```

When I start with nodemon server.js, node.js console runs quite OK

```
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
connect.multipart() will be removed in connect 3.0
info  - socket.io started
Listening on port 3030...
```

However, when I open browser and test app, I see errors in console

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery-minicolors.min.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < socket.io.js:1
```

I just don't know why these errors happens and how to fix them

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried explicitly adding `app.use(app.router);` after your `app.use(express.static(..));` ? Also, does `config.rootPath + '/public/socket.io/socket.io.js'` exist?

Answer (score 1):

This means that jquery-minicolors.min.js is actually an html document. make sure that the route is correct.

You're getting the same error on socket.io.js, make sure that when you hit "localhost:3030/socket.io/socket.io.js" that you are actually getting something.

Either way, the "unexpected <" comes from a 404 error html page.

Comment: Thanks Brian, based on your suggestion, I change to use socket-io.client

    script(type="text/javascript", src="/vendor/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.min.js")

instead of

    script(type="text/javascript", src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")

Now error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < socket.io.js:1" has gone !

the reason is that application can not find correct path to socket.io in client side

Comment: After modify correct path for jquery-mincolors, now error is fixed

Answer (score 0):

I am running an app built using JQuery Html and Css on browser using VS 2017 IDE. The app wouldn't run with a Chrome spinning wheel.

I unchecked the below checkbox and the app started running.
It might help someone some day.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this error too when setting up the server using node.js. The problem was that in server.js file I initialized the socket.io library with http argument before I created the server.

So I had

```
var http = require('http');
const io = require('socket.io', 'net')(http);
http.createServer(function(res,req) {
    ...
});
```

Corrected it to:

```
var http = require('http').createServer(handler);
const io = require('socket.io', 'net')(http);
```